# "__class magic method" (mediating references to class names by a custom code)

Tags: php, magic-methods

You can redirect calls to some properties/functions by using __get, __call.

Is there a way to do it for classes?

I would like to convert all mentions of some_class_name in the code to, MY_VERSION_some_class_name (not only for one class, it's a pattern).

This would be easy if methods / properties were the target of this renaming policy.

Can you think of a way to do it for classes in PHP?

Edit: I need this for referencing to different variants of classes in different situations. I need one class name to be resolved to different variants of this class, depending on a condition known at runtime, and persistent through the whole session.

Thanks

p.s.
If you are curious why I want to do this, look at [Maintaining variants of an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159920/global-design-issue-building-the-exact-version-of-an-application-at-runtime)

Answer (score 4):

You can't convert all mentions of some_class_name in the code to another class. However, you can use variables as class names:

```
$className = "MyClass";
$obj = new $className;
$className::myMethod();
```

All you have to do is change the variable and you will be using a different class. If you have to do this for a lot of classes, you might want to create some sort of factory for it.

```
$factory = System::getFactory();
$obj = $factory->getAuthObj();
```

Basically, the System class would return a different object based on what class needed to be used for that particular run time.

Comment: +1 for recommending a factory, rather than some other grim method. Factories often turn out useful anyway.

Comment: This is a good idea but will force me to refactor a big code. And also will look ugly - think of every mention of any class name looking like $factory->classVariant('classname') instead of simply classname

Comment: @gidireich Generally you would do `$factory->getMyModule()`. What happens is when you create `$factory`, you create the factory class that has the combination of classes you want.

Comment: @gidireich This is the price you pay for this particular bit of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

Aiden's untested approach: variable variables and generating a string:

```
<?php
$dog = "12";

function getDogClass($myNum)
{
    global $dog;
    // Do something dynamic here;
    $dog = "Dog_" . $myNum;
    return "dog";
}

class Dog_13rc1
{
    function __construct()
    {
        printf("Woof!");
    }
}

class Dog_12
{
    function __construct()
    {
        printf("Grrrr");
    }
}

$myObj = new ${getDogClass('13rc1')}();
?>
```

As long as the call to `getDogClass()` returns a string of the name of a variable in scope then you are good.

The output is `woof`.

This means the only refactoring you need is to find/replace occurences of the class name with that call.

But this is grim. and probably slow. Also, a maintenance/bug-tracking nightmare type of hack.

Answer (score 0):

The magic function you want is `__autoload`:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    // include your special class in here
    include $class_name . '.php'; 
}
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: This won't help him redirect which class is being used.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question directly, but *is* useful.This is useful, one of the tools I tried to harness - loading different versions of the class.